# Automatic calculation of error bars based on data in a bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, pgfmath, error-bars

I would like to draw a bar chart using PGFPlots with error bars that are automatically calculated from the data.

Here is a slightly simplified version of what I am attempting:

Suppose you have two programs `foo` and `bar`, and you are measuring how long they take to compile and what is their execution time.  You measure each of these metrics twice and end up with the following data:

```
program,measurement_no,compilation,execution
foo,1,4.2,10.2
foo,2,4.3,9.5
bar,1,2.5,6.6
bar,2,3.1,6.8
qux,1,10.1,8.0
qux,2,11.0,7.7
```

Here is my basic attempt at plotting this:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
program,measurement_no,compilation,execution
foo,1,4.2,10.2
foo,2,4.3,9.5
bar,1,2.5,6.6
bar,2,3.1,6.8
qux,1,10.1,8.0
qux,2,11.0,7.7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\Data


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        y dir=reverse,
        symbolic y coords={foo,bar,qux},
        ylabel=Program,xlabel={Time [s]},
        legend style={at={(.95,.5)},anchor=east},
    ]
        \addplot+ table [y=program,x=compilation] \Data;
        \addplot+ table [y=program,x=execution] \Data;
        \legend{compilation,execution};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Output of my code attempt]

Of course, there are several problems here, which are probably all related:

1. ~~Since there are two `x` values for each `y` ‘key’, there are duplicated rows in the chart~~ **UPDATE #1:** this is resolved by adding `ytick=data`
2. The two measurement values overlap each other – it would make more sense to take, for instance, their *arithmetic mean* and plot that
3. There are no error bars and naturally, just adding `error bars/y dir=both` won’t help without additional setup

---

**What I would want** is to display the mean compilation and execution times as the blue and red bars for each program and use the error bars feature of PGFPlots to show e.g. the standard deviation of the actual measurements from this mean.

I should also add that this is a simplified example and in reality, I have more measurements (10) and more bars to plot (around 5 bars for each program).

---

**UPDATE #1:** Okay, I overlooked that the duplicated `y` labels are caused by a missing `ytick=data` option. The main question is still unresolved.

Comment: Suggestion: Use R, which is built for such tasks. You can reuse results in Latex with packages like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rterface .

Comment: @MS-SPO: Thanks, that’s indeed a good alternative. I am more familiar with Python (and also prefer it much more) though, but perhaps it can also be integrated with LaTeX in sensible ways. Of course, there is the last resort of preprocessing my data with other tools (R, Python, whatever) and using `pgfplots` only for plotting the thus obtained values. I would still be interested in a LaTeX-only solution though.

Comment: Depends on how much time you want to spend. Probably latex3 will give you more options within Latex.